# Defining the route parameter from client side in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameter-passing

```
app.get('login/:id', function (request, response) {
  …
});
```

In a request like this, how does the :id parameter get set from the user? Each user will have a unique id on my site obviously.

Would the user have to login in for a id be set in default at the session? I'm just trying to understand the workflow because I am new to using express.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` parameter would be determined by the URL the client requests. For example, if the client requests `/login/foo`, then `id` would be `foo`.

Comment: How does the client request foo? I'm just confused on this vs sending objects of information in a request like I have and accessing it via req.propName

Comment: Lets say your website is example.com. If the client requests http://example.com/login/abc, then the `id` parameter would be abc. It's primarily useful for APIs, for example, when you want to define a route for example.com/posts/:user/id/:postId.

Answer (score 0):

Using `app.get('/login/:id', ...)` means that when someone accesses GET `/login/ABC` endpoint then your controller will get `ABC` in `req.params.id` and that's it. The `id` doesn't come from a session, it's just a part of the path included in the request.

It is a strange name for an endpoint. Usually you would have GET `/users/:id` to get a specific user (possibly with an alias of GET `/users/me` to get the user that is currently logged in). Here it's not clear what is the intention - is it a user's ID, or a session ID of a logged in user? In any case here it is just part of the request path.